# Express js : Content security header is not reflecting

Tags: javascript, express, helmet.js

In my express js application I have enabled the `helmet` for the security implementation

```
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.use(helmet(
));
```

After setting this i m getting CSP error in chrome console

> Refused to load the script
> 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note
> that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used
> as a fallback.
>
> localhost/:1

to resolve this I have added the following meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com/">
```

But still I m getting the error, i tried similar posts in the StackOverflow but nothing resolved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out the issue i have to set the CSP through helmet configuration

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: false,
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'","code.jquery.com","*.jsdelivr.net"],
        "style-src":["'self'","'unsafe-inline'","*.cloudflare.com","*.googleapis.com","*.jsdelivr.net"],
        "font-src":["'self'","*.gstatic.com","*.cloudflare.com","*.jsdelivr.net"],
        "img-src":["'self'","data:"]
      }
}));
```